# Django: How do I combine a list and a queryset, paginate both of them and iterate through them in the template?

Tags: django, list, templates, pagination, django-queryset

I'm finishing up my leader-board. I currently return the top 100 leaders for a given category. I need to attach the current rank to the results.

At first I tried the forloop.counter variable in the template, but since the results are paginated by 10 results at a time, each new page reset the counter.

```
    def leaderboard(request):
        stats = Leaderboard.objects.all().order_by('-most_hits')[:100]
        rank = list(range(1, 101))
        paginator = Paginator(stats, 10)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        results = paginator.get_page(page)
        context = {'results': results, 'rank': rank}
```

currently returning wrong rank on page 2,3 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer wasn't that hard: I just used zip to combine the list and queryset. For the pagination I just repeated the same paginate steps for the rank that I used for the queryset with new variable names. Finally, I iterated through the zipped variable in the template:

```
    def leaderboard(request):
        stats = Leaderboard.objects.all().order_by('-most_hits')[:100]
        rank = list(range(1, 101)) 
        paginator = Paginator(stats, 10)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        stats = paginator.get_page(page)  

        paginator2 = Paginator(rank, 10)
        page2 = request.GET.get('page')
        rank = paginator2.get_page(page2)

        rank_and_query = zip(rank, stats)
        context = {'rank_and_query': rank_and_query}
```

```
    {% for rank,stats in rank_and_query %}
        <li>{{ rank }} : {{ stats.leader }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
```